# Separating and identifying long and short term effects of statistical variables

Tags: time-series

A quick general question:

In a practical setting, what's a good way to separate out, and then comment on, long term and short effects in a model? I had thought a good way to do so would be to include lagged versions, of the same variable, of varying distances, the longer distances indicating longer term effects, but I cannot think of anything else.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cross Correlation Function will help to tell you what those relationships are. Do you have a specific data set you are trying to analyze that you can post or example?